# Complejidad algoritmo de búsqueda binaria

Tags: algoritmos, matemáticas

Quisiera saber porque el algoritmo de busqueda binaria tiene complejidad logaritmica, ya que estoy analizandolo y no logro ver dicha complejidad.

Aqui la implementacion en java.

```
public class Busqueda_Binaria {

public int Busqueda(int vector[], int dato) {

    int limiteSuperior = vector.length - 1;
    int limiteInferior = 0;     
    int centroVector = 0;        

    while (limiteInferior <= limiteSuperior) {

        centroVector = (limiteSuperior + limiteInferior) / 2;

        if (vector[centroVector] == dato) {
            return centroVector;
        }

        else if (dato < vector[centroVector]) {
            limiteSuperior = centroVector - 1;       
        }           

        else {         
            limiteInferior = centroVector + 1;       
        }      
    }

    return -1;   
}
```

}

Supongo que es el resultado de una operacion en la linea donde cambio el valor del "centroVector", pero no se porque se usa logaritmo.

Agradeceria una explicacion de como analizarlo correctamente, o una pequeña guia de como analizar algoritmos correctamente ya que no lo tengo muy claro.

Comment: Luis, tienes algun intento de analisis de complejidad que te gustaria incluir? Solo quiero saber ya que estoy preparando una respuesta y si tienes uno, podria ayudarte a terminarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando la respuesta que ha dado @ian Rosas y para dar un abrebocas al tema de complejidad algoritmica analicemos el juego entre dos personas, P1 y P2, que juegan a adivinar un número entre 1 y 500; la dinámica del juego es la siguiente:

1. P1 piensa un número (para este ejemplo el 499)
2. P2 dice un número `x` entre 1 y 500
3. P1 solo puede responder de tres formas
   `a)` responde `igual` si `x` es igual al número pensado y termina el juego 
   `b)` responde  `mayor` si el número pensado es mayor que `x`, o
   `c)` responde `menor` si el número pensado es menor que `x`
   en los casos `b)` y `c)` P2 vuelve a preguntar por otro número.

**Estrategias:**

La primera estrategía que puede usar P2 es la de iniciar en 1 e ir aumentando de 1 en 1 hasta adivinar el número, en este caso P2 tendría que hacer 499 preguntas (muy aburrido) y P1 contestaria 498 veces `mayor` y una vez `igual`. Este caso es similar al de hacer un ciclo `for` sobre un array que contenga los número de 1 a 500 (imagina si fuera hasta Un millon), la complejidad de esta estrategia es `O(n)`.

La segunda estrategia que puede seguir P2 es la de preguntar por el número de la mitad de los posibles candidatos, empecemos

P2: 250 --> P1: mayor

P2: 375 --> P1: mayor *aca se descartan lo menores a 250*

P2: 438 --> P1: mayor *en este punto se han descartado 375 números*

P2: 469 --> P1: mayor

P2: 484 --> P1: mayor

P2: 492 --> P1: mayor

P2: 496 --> P1: mayor

P2: 498 --> P1: mayor

P2: 499 --> P1: igual

En esta estrategia P2 solo realizo 9 preguntas (490 menos que la primera estrategia y mucho menos tiempo), ahora si calculamos el logaritmo en base 2 de 500 tenemos que es `8.9`. La complejidad de este algoritmo es precisamente `O(log2(n))`

Answer (score 1):

Es debido a que la busqueda binaria, lo que hace es partir en dos donde buscar recursivamente, hasta que lo encuentre, es decir nunca estas revisando todos los datos que se tiene en el arreglo, solo una parte,PERO solo se puede hacer si los datos estan previamente ordenados sino tu algoritmo no sera valido para ser O(logn). Te recomiendo ver libros de Big O ya que en ellos puedes ver mas acerca del tema.

Answer (score 0):

```
K = 2
while ( i<=n && i > 1 )  |   n
 i = i /K                |
while end                |
```

El conteo de operaciones es:

```
n + n +  n + ... + n        (Donde K=2  ,  K^1=2 , K^2=4)
    _    _         _
    K^1  K^2       K^n
```

Esto se expresa como una sumatoria de potencias decrecientes relacionadas con divición (log.)  , de ser crecientes relacionadas con multiplicación seríam exponenciales.

```
Sumatoria n               (-i)
          _        = n*(k)
          K^(i)
```

Disculpa la mala documentación.